# How to correctly delete a pointer after using new operator? Code Keeps Throwing Error

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, delete-operator

So I keep getting the same error when trying to delete pointers after I've used the new operator.
I've checked online for ages and can't wrap my head around whats going on, I'm very new to C++ and am working on a university assignment.

Additionally I've successfully used new and delete operators for integer arrays and have not run into issues. So I'm very confused, hopefully I've just done something stupid.

ANY help or direction would be great. For context the program is trying to solve some quadratic equations.

You can see my code and error below. The entire program runs correctly until it get to the destructor and then I get a pop up to say "Exception Thrown: Task2.2.exe has triggered a breakpoint."

The screen then jumps to a break point in delete_scalar.cpp and shows the following:

```
_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void __CRTDECL operator delete(void* const block) noexcept
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    _free_dbg(block, _UNKNOWN_BLOCK);
    #else
    free(block);
    #endif
}
```

CODE BELOW:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class userValue
{
private:
    double* a;
    double* b;
    double* c;
    double discrim;

public:
    userValue(double*, double*, double*);
    ~userValue();
    void calcDiscrim();
    void displayAns();
};

userValue::userValue(double *x, double *y, double *z)
{
    discrim = 0;
    a = new double;
    a = x;
    cout << "a: " << *a;
    b = new double;
    b = y;
    cout << "b: " << *b;
    c = new double;
    c = z;
    cout << "c: " << *c;
    
}

userValue::~userValue()
{
    delete a, b, c;
}

void userValue::calcDiscrim()
{
    discrim = *b * *b - (4 * *a * *c);
}

void userValue::displayAns()
{
    double numerator, denominator, root1, root2;
    if (discrim > 0)
    {
        cout << "The discriminant: " << discrim << " is nonnegative, now we'll solve the rest of the formula" << endl;
        numerator = (-*b + sqrt(discrim));
        denominator = 2 * *a;
        root1 = numerator / denominator;
        cout << "The first root is: " << root1 << endl;

        numerator = (-*b - sqrt(discrim));
        denominator = 2 * *a;
        root2 = numerator / denominator;
        cout << "The second root is: " << root2 << endl;

    }
    else {
        cout << "The discriminant: " << discrim << " is negative and there are no real roots" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    cout << "Enter the variables to be used in the quadratic equation: " << endl;
    cout << "Enter a value for the variable 'a': ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter a value for the variable 'b': ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter a value for the variable 'c': ";
    cin >> c;

    double* j = new double(a);
    double* k = new double(b);
    double* l = new double(c);

    userValue defineInputs(j, k, l);
    defineInputs.calcDiscrim();

    defineInputs.displayAns();

    delete j, k, l;
    return 0;                                               //Return nothing
}
```

Comment: `a = new double;` allocates space for one `double` and stores the address of the allocated memory in `a`. `a = x;` stores the value of `x` in `a`. `a` no longer holds the address of the allocated memory. That address has been thrown away, and there is no way to get it back. The code cannot delete tha allocated block.

Comment: `delete j, k, l;` does not do what you expect. It uses the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) and is equivalent to `delete l;`.

Comment: As mentionned in existing answer, there is no reason to uses pointers here. If you really want pointers, then you have obvious errors in your code:
`a = x;` should be `*a = *x;`. You clearly don't want to update pointers here but the value. Same for the other two variables. Alternatively `a = new double(*x);` would also works with one less line of code.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you very much, that was extremely useful, I've now changed `a = x;` to `*a = *x;` and this works now but reading another answer maybe it's better than I simply remove all pointers. Thanks again!!

Comment: I haven't used `new` directly in about 10 years, and in my opinion it should not be used unless you are making your own smart pointer because the standard C++ library ones are insufficient for some particular use case. Your first choice ought to be objects, followed by smart pointers and containers.

Comment: Allocating a single scalar with `new`, like `new double` or `new int`, is almost certainly wrong. There is no advantage whatsoever compared to a simple scalar `double` or `int`, while being slower (requires indirection), more complicated, and using more memory.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm thank you for that, I didn't realise that was the case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, remove all pointers, new and delete from your code.

There is no need for it anywhere.

Literally remove every call to both, and remove every `*` (except when being used to multiply), and your code becomes correct.

---

Not for this problem, but in other situations, you need to read up on the rule of five, and use `unique_ptr` by default, and call `make_unique` instead of `new` directly.

---

Specific problems causing your crash include calling `new`, then immediately assigning over the pointer, losing track of that new pointer.  Then you double delete.

But as noted, nothing in your code shown should be using pointers.

Comment: I understand thank you very much, is there any reason they should be used when multiplying however?

Comment: @JoelGray I would be curious to know how you perform a multiplication without the `*` sign... True, in theory, you can write `c = exp(log(a)+log(b))`, but that's just 100 times slower and less precise!

Comment: @prapin Oh I thought they meant that the variables being multiplied must include the `*` symbol when the multiply/* symbol is being used on them. I.e `*a * *b;` as opposed to the correct `a * b;` But now I realise they were just being extremely verbose in their explanation of when and where to use the `*`, and were just trying to make sure I didn't remove the multiplication `*`.